# f is 1-1 mapping of X onto Y, prove that $f^{-1}$ is a 1-1 mapping of Y onto X

Tags: functions

I need to prove the following theorem.

> $f$ is 1-1 mapping of $X$ onto $Y$, prove that $f^{-1}$ is a 1-1
>   mapping of $Y$ onto $X$.

Since I have to prove this theorem it is assumed that this has to be true. But I found an issue.
If $\exists$ x $\in$ X such that $f(x) \neq y \in Y$, i.e there exist some x which is unmapped, function can still be 1-1. But if we consider the inverse of this function $f^{-1} : Y \to X$, it is not surjective, since the statement $\forall$ x $\exists$ y : $f^{-1}(y) = x$ is not true. Therefore it is not a 1-1 mapping.
Am I correct? If not, could you please prove the theorem.

UPDATED
Guys I understood the issue written above. Could you please help me out with the proof of this theorem ?

Comment: Exactly the definition of function says each x(in domain) must be mapped to unique y . So some x is not mapped  means it's not a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $x \in X$ we have $f(x)\in Y$. Call this $y$ then $f^{-1}(y)=x$.

Comment: What if $ f : R \to R^{+} = \sqrt{x}$ then we have for x = -1 f(-1) is not defined, i.e unmapped .

Comment: @Rustem Sadykov the above example is not a function because for a function defined each x(domain) must be mapped

Comment: @RustemSadykov The main point in this question is $f$ is  a function from  $X$ to $Y$ which means for every $x \in X$ there is a unique $y$ in $Y$ such that $f(x)=y$.